# mysql select dates in 30-day range

Tags: mysql, date

This must be simple but I fiddled with it, and didn't get anything I wanted. I have the following code:

```
SELECT id,title,start_date 
  FROM events 
 WHERE start_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
  AND city = '$cityName' 
ORDER BY start_date DESC
```

Now this selects events with dates in this month, but the definition of this month shown in query is different than what I need. I need it to show me events within 30 days and not only this month i.e. august. If I insert an event in august it shows the outcome. If I do insert september, it doesn't even though it is less than 30 days away.

Comment: "...I fiddled with it..." Great! Hurry up and post your [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so that we can fiddle with it too.

Comment: haha didn't fiddle there to be honest..more like in development environment but thanks for the great resource mate

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should change `1 MONTH` to `30 DAY`:

```
WHERE start_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

To limit it to 30 days in either direction:

```
WHERE start_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
AND start_date < NOW() + INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: @sys_debug: Do you want an end date? Do you want it to be within 30 days before or after? Is there a column called `end_date`?

Comment: actually no thanks but this still doesn't work...it doesn't show the entry with start_date of 2012-09-06

Comment: @sys_debug: Nice. Glad you found the problem.

Answer (score 3):

How about like this:

```
...WHERE DATE(start_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) and DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND city...
```

Answer (score 2):

OR

`AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,YOURDATE,now()) < 30`

This gives you a 30 day span

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help also

```
SELECT id,title,start_date 
  FROM events 
 WHERE  city = "$cityName" AND 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,start_date,now()) < 30   
ORDER BY start_date DESC
```