# How to retrieve the last 30 days records for a user from current date

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I'm new to mysql and i wanted to frame a query to retrieve last 30 days records for a particular user_id .  Here is the sample table below and i'm kinda stumped with it any help ?

```
transaction_id | user_id    | activities_id | time, 
4              |  19        |    1          | 2015-04-06 14:44:35       
5              |  19        |    6          | 2015-04-06 14:45:27
```

Also please find the format of my table given below:

```
 transaction_id:  'int(10) unsigned','NO','PRI',NULL,'auto_increment'
 user_id:          'int(10) unsigned','YES','MUL',NULL,''
 activities_id:    'int(10) unsigned','YES','',NULL,''
 time:             'datetime','YES','',NULL,''
```

Comment: Come on. You must be able to make some sort of effort

Comment: It is duplicate - this is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12098911/1726419

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql select dates in 30-day range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098899/mysql-select-dates-in-30-day-range)

Comment: Im sorry question should have been framed little better ... sorry about that folks i have edited my question hope its clear now atleast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT  * FROM  table 
WHERE time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Comment: Thanks @Thanos Markou that worked given that my question was wrong initially thanks for giving me the quick solution 

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() and user_id = 19`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

select * from table i where i.time <= now() and i.timesta >=date_sub(now(), interval 7 day)
      and w.timestamp <= now() and w.timestamp >= date_sub(now(), interval 7 day);