# How to retrieve the last 30 days of activity for each user since their last activity

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id | user_id | campaign_id | mydate
1  |      19 |           1 | 2017-11-08 
2  |      19 |           6 | 2017-10-10
3  |      19 |           5 | 2017-10-06
4  |      20 |           4 | 2017-06-06
5  |      20 |           3 | 2017-05-18
6  |      20 |           2 | 2017-01-01
```

and my goal is to retain the campaign_id for those opened in the last 30 days since the last action of each user_id.

Pretty much in the spirit of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098899/mysql-select-dates-in-30-day-range/12098911#12098911) but in my case the upper bound for the date is not NOW() for everybody, but the date when they did their last activity.

So for user 19 it will be only:

```
1  |      19 |           1 | 2017-11-08 
2  |      19 |           6 | 2017-10-10
```

While for user 20 it will be only:

```
4  |      20 |           4 | 2017-06-06
5  |      20 |           3 | 2017-05-18
```

That switch from the NOW() to the "every user_id has its own value" is something I cannot articulate:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Comment: You mean the 30 days prior to their last activity?

Comment: yes I mean precisely that

Comment: why a downvote? what is not clear?

Comment: Not my downvote, but if I was to hazard a guess, it might be because you failed to address points as discussed here: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id, MAX(mydate) mydate FROM my_table GROUP BY user_id) y         
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
   AND y.mydate -  INTERVAL 30 DAY < x.mydate;
```